# Running Visual FoxPro reports on Win 2008 / 2012 server

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

We a Visual FoxPro application that currently runs on machines with Windows 7.  We are building the application with Visual FoxPro 9.0 Service Pack 2.  We are looking at running this application on a Windows 2012 Server with RDS.  The one problem I have run into is running our reports.  For the currency values that are printed on the reports they almost always show up as asterisks.  Also, several non-numeric fields have the last character cut off.  We are currently setting the REPORTBEHAVIOR to 80.  We have over 100 reports and therefore it is not possible to extend the length of all the fields in every report.  Before I tell my boss that we cannot use Windows 2012 Server I would like to do my due diligence to see if there is some setting or something that would fix this problem.

First of all, is this a GDI Plus vs. GDI problem?

Secondly, can anybody give help me figure out how to fix this problem?  I have searched the internet but cannot find anybody that has run into this specific problem.

Comment: You might try seeking help at one of these popular FoxPro community sites:     Universal Thread ( https://www.universalthread.com )      
Foxite ( https://www.foxite.com/ )      
Tek-Tips ( http://www.tek-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=184 )    
MSDN FoxPro forum ( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=visualfoxprogeneral )

Comment: And the leafe.com Visual FoxPro mailing lists, where a lot of very long-time developers hang out.

Comment: We have many sites on Server 2012 perfectly fine. This smells like a printer driver issue to me. When the report prints, what make of printer is it going to? Is it the same for all printers? Is the screen preview the same?

Comment: This may be too simplistic, but is there a chance that the reports are set to use a default font and the default fonts used by the Server 2012 are different and are thus altering the spacing and size of your report fields?

Comment: You could probably have just copied Arialn*.ttf from a desktop PC that had Office already into the fonts folder on the server and installed the font too.

Comment: @Gene S - Thanks I added it.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too simplistic, but is there a chance that the reports are set to use a default font and the default fonts used by the Server 2012 are different and are thus altering the spacing and size of your report fields?

Comment: This answer clued me into the correct answer. We use Arial Narrow on our reports and that font is not installed on Windows 2012 server. It is however installed with Office and so installing Office on this machine resolved my problem.